# Machine epsilon with Numba

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to accelerate my code using Numba.In my code, I have to use the machine epsilon declared in `numpy.finfo(float).eps` which is equal to `2**-52` according to the documentation. My question is the following:

Is there something to replace the machine eps in Numba?

if Not, is declaring it as a constant has any drawback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.finfo(np.float64).eps` in Numba `njit` functions. This works well with Numba 0.54.1. See the following code:

```py
@nb.njit('float64()')
def test():
    return np.finfo(np.float64).eps
test() # Returns 2.220446049250313e-16
```

Declaring a constant is also fine. In both cases Numba generate a good assembly code that directly return the (precomputed) constant.